# Using ASCII in .htaccess

Tags: html, apache, ascii

I'm trying to create my own local network website. I want to add some parts that are password protected with .htaccess . The guide that I read said that they have to be saved with ASCII encoding and I cant figure out how to do that.

I tried selecting the UTF-8 button in the bottom right hand corner of VSCode but ASCII is not an option that the file can be saved as.

Comment: save as utf-8 and check whether it works

Comment: ISO 8859-1 is the same as ASCII (more or less).

Comment: @HereticMonkey, that would "more", by 128 codepoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't use any extended characters, you can save as UTF-8 and it will be equivalent to ASCII.

UTF-8 encoding uses an upper bit to signal that a codepoint outside of the normal ASCII range is to be used.  If you don't use non-ASCII characters, there is no problem.

Comment: ok, I tried it, the login works but after the webpage says 500 error caused by server overload or a CGI script.

Comment: @dragonbeast Check your logs.  It probably doesn't have anything to do with your config file.

Comment: Oh, Thank you! It had something to do with the permissions for where the password file was located.